# How can I calculate the intersection of two ordinary intervals in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, intersection, intervals

Intervals are given by their boundaries as arrays [a,b] and [x,y]. I would like to calculate the length of the intersection between them. According to this page: http://world.std.com/~swmcd/steven/tech/interval.html

I can tell it is 0 if

```
(not (a < y && x < b))
```

holds.

For example interval [1.2,4.3] and [2.1,5.5] intersection length is 4.3 - 2.1 = 2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it.

**Code**

```
def length(a,b,p)
  [[a.last,b.last].min - [a.first,b.first].max,0].max.round(p)
end
```

**Examples**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an OO solution of the same problem. I suggest to build a custom `Interval` class, but this implementation is only an example and the asker should think it over with respect to his actual case:

```
class Interval
  attr_reader :range

  def initialize range
    @range = if range.nil? then nil else
               fail TypeError, "Begin greater than end!" if range.begin > range.end
               Range.new( range.begin, range.end )
             end
  end

  def - other
    begin
      self.class.new [ range.begin, other.range.begin ].max ..
                     [ range.end, other.range.end ].min
    rescue TypeError
      self.class.new nil
    end
  end

  def size
    range.nil? ? 0 : range.end - range.begin
  end
end

def Interval a, b # a convenience constructor
  Interval.new a .. b
end

( Interval( 1.2, 4.3 ) - Interval( 2.1, 5.5 ) ).size
#=> 2.199999999999997
```

Comment: I'm sure Boris is aware of this, but the only `self.` needed here is the first one (as `self` is the default receiver for methods `Range#begin` and `Range#end`).  Some Rubyists elect to include `self.` when it's not needed for stylistic reasons.

Comment: If you change the first interval in your example to `( 5.6, 6.3 )` you get `=> -0.09999999999999964`.  As this is to be the length of the intersection, you need `[..., 0].max`.  No reply req'd as I'll delete this comment once you've seen it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thank you for pointing out the deficiency in my solution. It seems that `Range` is not a good parent class to rely upon when defining `Interval` class after all. I'll change the solution. In any case, this is not for the asker to copy and paste, only to inspire his own OO solution. As for the `begin` and `end` methods, `self` is needed for syntactic reason, as `begin` and `end` are at the same times reserved keywords in Ruby. You cannot write `def size; end - begin; end`, because the parser would take the first end to mean end of the method.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification re `self.`.  I overlooked about `begin` and `end` being keywords (and didn't test--tsk, tsk).  In fact, `self` in `self.class` is needed for that very reason. I'll have to keep that in mind in other situations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it really turns out that `Range` is not a good father class for `Interval`. The implementation turned less elegant with problem handling :-(. In any case, the `self.end - self.begin` line disappeared in the updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

just for future reference - in `MySQL` Cary`s answer would be (without the rounding part):

```
GREATEST( LEAST(`a_last`, `b_last`) - GREATEST(`a_first`, `b_first`), 0 )
```